# I need delete this line on svg

Tags: html, svg, background-color

I'm drawing a svg in html, when i draw this i get that line

[image]

and i dont want it, how i can sove it, this is my code

`html
<svg style="background-color: #fff" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="100" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 20" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <path fill="#f2f2f2" d="M0 30 V12 Q30 17 55 5 T100 11 V30z" />
</svg>`

after the line is another dive, its like a space between svg and another div

Answer (score 1):

That line isn't part of your SVG shape- the height of your shape is 30px but your viewbox is only 20px high - you just need to change `viewBox="0 0 100 20"` to `viewBox="0 0 100 30"` so that the whole shape is in your viewport.

Answer (score 0):

I opened it up in illustrator and that line is actually the edge of the artboard. I resized the art board and re-exported the code. I hope this helps. Unfortunately it did cram in some extra info.

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 1440 150" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1440 150;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:none;}
    .st1{fill:#F2F2F2;}
</style>
<path class="st0" d="z"/>
<path class="st1" d="M0,150V60c288,16.7,552,5,792-35s456-30,648,30v95H0z"/>
<path class="st0" d="z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Not work with that, its the same line, its like a space between divs, i cant remove it